# How to create desktop (or task bar) shortcut to eclipse IDE on Debian LXDE, OpenBox?

Tags: debian, shortcuts, desktop, openbox, lxde

Using Debian (Wheezy) with LXDE/OpenBox.

I know how to add shortcut items(panel applets) to panel at the bottom - as shortcut to some application. But, with Eclipse IDE its different, because Eclipse comes as separate folder, inside which is executable "eclipse" file. Eclipse is not installed via repositories (using apt-get, or Synaptic manager) and therefore it is not integrated as other software under certain start menu application category.

So, basically my question is "How can I add a shortcut (either on Desktop or bottom panel) that is shortcut to certain file"?

(There isn't any "Send to Desktop/Create a shortcut" option in LXDE)

Comment: Can't you just drag and drop on the bar itself?

Comment: No. "Drag and drop" does nothing if I try to put eclipse file somewhere on/above the bar. It seems like there isn't an option to make a shortcut to some file if that file is not categorized in applications menu.

Comment: @Virusboy I saw some posts that shortcuts should be made with  `.desktop` files.